# Can't filter out variable products in sale from wp_get_products loop (or shortcode)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, loop

I'm trying to filter out all **products in sale** from a WooCommerce loop. So the goal is to create a loop of products that are **new**, but doesn't contain sale products. The problem is that the products are all variable products. I've tried using regular shortcodes and now I'm trying to achieve this using a custom loop (wp_get_products). Still I can't figure out why it's not working the way it should.

I hope someone can help me with this.

My current custom loop using wp_get_products (not working):

```
  if(!function_exists('wc_get_products')) {
    return;
  }

  $date_range              = strtotime ( '-8 days' );

  $paged                   = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
  $products_per_page       = apply_filters('loop_shop_per_page', wc_get_default_products_per_row() * wc_get_default_product_rows_per_page());

  $recentProducts       = wc_get_products(array(
    'meta_key'             => '_price',
    'status'               => 'publish',
    'limit'                => $products_per_page,
    'page'                 => $paged,
    'paginate'             => true,
    'return'               => 'ids',
    'orderby'              => 'date',
    'order'                => 'DESC',
    'date_query'           => array(
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year'  => date('Y', $date_range ),
                'month' => date('m', $date_range ),
                'day'   => date('d', $date_range ),
            ),
        )
    )
  ));

  var_dump($recentProducts);

  wc_set_loop_prop('current_page', $paged);
  wc_set_loop_prop('is_paginated', wc_string_to_bool(true));
  wc_set_loop_prop('page_template', get_page_template_slug());
  wc_set_loop_prop('per_page', $products_per_page);
  wc_set_loop_prop('total', $recentProducts->total);
  wc_set_loop_prop('total_pages', $recentProducts->max_num_pages);

  if($recentProducts) {
    do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
      foreach($recentProducts->products as $recentProduct) {
        $productObject = wc_get_product( $recentProduct );

        //if ( !$productObject->is_on_sale() ) {
            $post_object = get_post($recentProduct);
            setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object);
            wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
        //}

      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');
  } else {
    do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
  }
```

Above code outputs all products that are published the last 8 days (which is good). The thing is that I don't know how to filter out the variable sale products within the wp_get_products function. I've tried using meta_query, but this only seems to work for simple products.

I've also tried to achieve this using the default WooCommerce shortcode, like so:

```
echo do_shortcode('[recent_products per_page="16" orderby="date" paginate="true" on_sale="false"]');
```

Unfortunately, on_sale="false" is not supported it seems.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to ask WooCommerce's support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some digging around I've finally found the answer I was looking for. Turns out there is a function called `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` you can use to exclude those ID's from `wc_get_products`.

So for anyone having the same problem.. you can use `'exclude' => wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` within your wp_get_products args and you're all set!